HRV analysis from .mibf beat file using RHRV package
Is there a way to conduct HRV analysis using the R package RHRV, where my ECG data is in the .mibf (machine independent beat file) format?  .mibf files are ASCII text files.
It looks like the package can only handle input files that specify the time of occurrence of each beat.
